# How to get the User Details from Azure B2C Active Directory with User Id

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

I have the user id of a user. I want to fetch the user details from B2C Active Directory with the user id. Is it possible to do that?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

yes it is possible

```
> B2C Get-User <user-object-id>
> B2C Get-User <filter-query-expression>
```

for more details look into search user

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-devquickstarts-graph-dotnet